# Why can't I throw an IOException from my Parcelable.writeToParcel(Parcel, int)?

Tags: android, ioexception, parcelable

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) throws IOException {
   doSomethingThatThrowsIOException();
}
```

Quoth the compiler:

> Exception IOException is not compatible with throws clause in
>   Parcelable.writeToParcel(Parcel, int)

I don't see a throws clause anywhere in the docs or the actual `Parcelable` code. Is this a pesky threading issue?

Comment: I can't accept everybody's answer, I'll give credit to the noob. Thanks all for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "writeToParcel" method is overridden from the parent class: Parcel. When you override a method, you can't change nor the signature nor the throws clause of the original method.

The two options are: externalize the stuff that throws IOException
OR Handle the exception inside a try - catch block...

Answer (score 3):

`Parcelable.writeToParcel(Parcel, int)` in `Parcelable`does not throw IOException. So if you extend the class and define your own `writeToParcel(Parcel, int)`, it can't throw a checked exception that is not in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

That's the exact problem, IOException is a checked exception, and must be rethrown or caught. If the `super` don't throw this exception, you can't as well.

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/exceptions.html) §11.2:

> The checked exception classes named in the throws clause are part of
>   the contract between the implementor and user of the method or
>   constructor. The throws clause of an overriding method may not specify
>   that this method will result in throwing any checked exception which
>   the overridden method is not permitted, by its throws clause, to
>   throw. When interfaces are involved, more than one method declaration
>   may be overridden by a single overriding declaration. In this case,
>   the overriding declaration must have a throws clause that is
>   compatible with all the overridden declarations (§9.4).